# Apache Intranet and SSH Tunneling

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, intranet

I'm trying to configure Apache to serve some intranet pages. Access to the intranet is made using SSH tunneling. Using the tunnel, I would like to access http://intranet.boss and expect those pages, but instead I get "connection refused" in Firefox.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/boss
ServerName intranet.boss
```

Something like this.

Later: Working!

I needed to add `127.0.0.1 intranet.boss` to /etc/hosts file.

Comment: what command are you using to establish your tunnel? Is apache definitely listening on port 80 (netstat)?

Comment: are you sure that client will access 127.0.0.1 and not other ip?
change configuration to `listen 0.0.0.0:80` and limit users/virtualhost by source ip's

Comment: @GeoSword I was using Putty's tunneling feature.

Comment: @GioMac yes, only 127.0.0.1, so that it will be accessible only by ssh tunneling.

Comment: I've edited my question. Problem solved. Thanks guys!

Comment: you can answer you own question and mark it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the SOCKS proxy feature in SSH instead of port forwarding.  With most command-line SSH clients, it's the `-D` option.  Then, once you configure your browser to use the SOCKS proxy, you can just go to `http://intranet.boss/`, without having to hack `/etc/hosts`.